# How to give padding(all sides) to a value inside NumericUpDown Control in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I am stuck with this problem of giving padding to all sides to a **value** inside NumericUpDown control in Winforms.

Apparently no one has asked this before.

Actual how control is looking: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIweV.png)
Expected how I want control to look: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6SZL.png)

Ignore other differences in both the attached images. Just need to pad the value from top, bottom and left; as part of this question.

So far, I have only figured out that there is a TextAlign property which can align either Left or Right or Center, but that doesn't help in giving padding to top and bottom edges of the control.

Below code is not solving my problem
this.numericUpDown1.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't control the height of a winforms NumericUpDown control, and therefor it's text-aling property only allows left, center, and right (as opposed to, say, a label which has 9 possibilities (TopLeft, MiddleCenter, BottomRight and so on).
You can, however, create your own control to replace the built in numericUpDown,  but that's going to take a lot of work.
Perhaps someone have already done this work and released an open source somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The `NumericUpDown` control has an internal [`UpDownEdit`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UpDownBase.cs,1249) child derives from the `TextBox` control used to display and edit the value. You can p/invoke to set the *Left* and/or the *Right* margins of a single-line `TextBox`. Add to that the *Top* and/or *Bottom* margins of a multiline `TextBox`.

Consider the listed extension class which targets the derived types from the [`TextBoxBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) abstract class. It adds the `SetInnerMargin` method to these types to set the inner margins. Note, for the single-line text boxes, the values of the Top and Bottom properties of the `Padding` struct are ignored.

```cs
// TextBox, RichTextBox...etc.
public static class TextBoxBaseExtensions
{
    private const int EM_SETRECT = 0xB3;
    private const int EM_SETMARGINS = 0xD3;

    private const int EC_LEFTMARGIN = 0x1;
    private const int EC_RIGHTMARGIN = 0x2;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;

        public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            Left = left;
            Top = top;
            Right = right;
            Bottom = bottom;
        }

        public RECT(Rectangle r)
        {
            Left = r.Left;
            Top = r.Top;
            Right = r.Right;
            Bottom = r.Bottom;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, ref RECT rect);

    public static void SetInnerMargin(this TextBoxBase self, Padding pad)
    {
        if (self.Multiline)
        {
            var r = new Rectangle(
                pad.Left, 
                pad.Top, 
                self.ClientSize.Width - pad.Left - pad.Right, 
                self.ClientSize.Height - pad.Top - pad.Bottom);
            var nr = new RECT(r);

            SendMessage(self.Handle, EM_SETRECT, 0, ref nr);
        }
        else
        {
            SendMessage(
                self.Handle,
                EM_SETMARGINS, EC_LEFTMARGIN | EC_RIGHTMARGIN,
                pad.Right * 0x10000 + pad.Left);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage examples:

```cs
var pad = new Padding(5);

textBox1.SetInnerMargin(pad);
richTextBox1.SetInnerMargin(pad);
(numericUpDown1.Controls[1] as TextBox).SetInnerMargin(pad);
```

Make sure that the handles of the target controls are created and assigned before you call this method. Alternatively, subscribe to their `HandleCreated` events to call it.

Also, you can create custom controls to implement this feature. For example:

```cs
public class NumericUpDownEx : NumericUpDown
{
    private Padding inMargin = Padding.Empty;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the inner margins. The Left and Right only.
    /// The Top and Bottom margins are ignored.
    /// </summary>
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Padding), "0, 0, 0, 0")]
    public Padding InnerMargin
    {
        get => inMargin;
        set
        {
            if (inMargin != value)
            {
                inMargin = value;
                SetInnerMargins();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="TextBox.TextAlign"/>
    new public HorizontalAlignment TextAlign
    {
        get => base.TextAlign;
        set
        {
            if (base.TextAlign != value)
            {
                base.TextAlign = value;
                SetInnerMargins();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        SetInnerMargins();
    }

    private void SetInnerMargins()
    {
        if (Controls[1] is TextBox tb)
            tb.SetInnerMargin(InnerMargin);
    }
}
```

[image: SO74470685]